# jquery accordion doesn't work with a href links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I have an accordion but it fails to slide open where there are link  tags within the div.   I am using jquery 1.11, live link here: santaclaratailgating.com/test (the first FAQ accordion doesn't work):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

});
});

 </script>
<style>
.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
 .accordion-content {display: none; font-size: 120%; font-weight: bold; color:#00458D;align:left;text-align:left; }
 .accordion-content.default {display: block;}
</style>


<div id="accordion">
<h4 class="accordion-toggle">accordion title</h4>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>test <a href="hi.com">a</a>  </p>

</div>
<h4 class="accordion-toggle">accordion title2</h4>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>works fine</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works just fine, check the Demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/nf1kmkj0/ -- What version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: Athena, Great bro, i'm hungry now. :)) I just gave it a test clicked on Faq and its works on Chrome and IE. What browser are you using?

Comment: Ha they make some great food.  I am using Chrome and specifically I clicked on Faq and then clicked on "So, How do I order?"

Comment: You have (<a id="faq" name="faq">
    <h4 class="accordion-toggle">So, how do I order?</h4>
  </a>) -- so what is the id for (how to order). I think its not going anywere because you are there allready

Comment: Doh!  Hungry minds think much better ;).  Thanks man

Comment: If you put (<a href="#contact">So, how do I order?</a>) where (<h4 class="accordion-toggle">So, how do I order?</h4>) and style the <a> it will work. Unless you want the accordion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

});
});
```

```css
.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
 .accordion-content {display: none; font-size: 120%; font-weight: bold; color:#00458D;align:left;text-align:left; }
 .accordion-content.default {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
<h4 class="accordion-toggle">accordion title</h4>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>test <a href="hi.com">a</a>  </p>

</div>
<h4 class="accordion-toggle">accordion title2</h4>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>works fine</p>
</div>
</div>
```